# Notations For Typo Corrections In Chinese Texts

Tags: notation

English typo corrections work kind of like this:

> yeah, it's really food
>
> *good

where an asterisk marks a correction from the above line.

- What Notations Are There For Typo Corrections In Chinese Texts?

Comment: Your example seems to imply the extent is internet usage, is it?

Comment: Internet or SMS, really.

Comment: I'm fairly sure chinese people just retype mistakes. I asked a couple of people today about something similar to the "*" symbol, but they were baffled by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

These are the notations for corrections in text. What you are asking for is No.4.

Comment: Is No.4 type able?

Comment: Actually, these formal notations are used in Chinese course.